# How to perform full index refresh in solrcloud

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am evaluating SolrCloud and am wondering if anyone can comment or provide a link on how to perform full-indexing in SolrCloud. Due to dictionary changes and so on, I need to build the index from scratch periodically and it is not very clear to me how I can do that. Should I have multiple clusters?

Comment: How did you originally build your index? XML, Data Import Handler, etc?

Comment: I built a large json index file and used it to index. Before SolrCloud, I used a dedicate master node and a set of slave nodes so things are more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for now is to build a new cluster on the fly (I am using EC2) for full refresh and then swap with the cluster in action.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think creating a new cluster periodically and swapping it up is a solution to this problem.I understand you can use ELB for this purpose but still it's not the way to go.

Why can't you reindex your data periodically on the same cluster.Just use a clean attribute alongside your regular indexing command.

Comment: would you elaborate on your suggestion? It looks much simpler but I am not sure what you meant by "clean" attribute? An example would be great.